# Error Setting Index of DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: .net, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I am working with a `DataGridView` that has one column that is made of `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`.  The way my program populates these `ComboBoxCells` is that it polls out local database for specific values and sets them up that way.

This I am having no problem with.

What I **am** having a problem with, is when I try to programmatically change which value in the ComboBoxCell is shown 'by Default'.  I have 'by Default' in quotes because I am not really trying to change the Default value of the cell, just change the value that is displayed by the time the user sees the column added to the `DataGridView`.

Currently I am getting the following error in my program:

> System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

Now this is the code I am attempting to use to get this to work:

```
Dim dgvcc As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
For Each row As DataRow In suppliers.Rows
    dgvcc.Items.Add(row.Item("Supplier").ToString())
Next
dg.Item("Supplier", rowNum) = dgvcc
dg.Item("Supplier", rowNum).Value = dgvcc.Items.IndexOf(supplier)
```

A few notes about the above code:

1. `suppliers` is a DataTable` object which holds the data retrieved from the database
2. `rowNum` is just an Integer variable set up to be the row the data is being added to
3. `dg` is my `DataGridView` object

Now I have run this code with the debugger to confirm that *yes*, the value I am trying to get the index of in the last line of code does exist in the combo box list.

If I change the last line to:

```
dg.Item("Supplier", rowNum).Value = dgvcc.Items(0)
```

Then I don't get the error.  So my issue seems to be with trying to set the value to a specific index, but I am not sure what about my code is wrong.  Is there another way to set the current value of a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` other than what I am trying to do?

Note: While I am programming in VB.Net, I will accept C# answers as well :)

Answer (score 0):

So I found out my problem.  I needed to change:

```
dg.Item("Supplier", rowNum).Value = dgvcc.Items.IndexOf(supplier)
```

To

```
dg.Item("Supplier", rowNum).Value = dgvcc.Items().Item(dgvcc.Items.IndexOf(supplier))
```